# What does <> mean in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'm a beginner with neo4j and I was looking at one of their examples (with the goal of "recommend 3 actors that Keanu Reeves should work with (but hasn't)"):

```
MATCH (keanu:Person {name:"Keanu Reeves"})-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(c),
      (c)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coc)
WHERE coc <> keanu  AND NOT((keanu)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coc))
RETURN coc.name, count(coc)
ORDER BY count(coc) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

however, in "coc <> keanu" (third line), I do not know what <> signifies. Can someone clarify this for me? I tried looking up in the manual and other places, but could not find it. Thanks!

Comment: It is documented [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypher-comparison)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"<>" in the WHERE phrase means "not equal", and is functionally equivalent to

```
NOT (a = b)
```

In some languages this would be expressed as "!="

In the context you're citing, "coc <> keanu" means "any node with an ACTED_IN relationship to something, not including the node corresponding to Keanu Reeves"